# Why i am getting wrong string of dynamic length using pointers in C from stdin?

Tags: c

I am trying to receive a string of unidentified length in C through pointers and realloc() function but after the string became 30 character long , the first few characters are like this :

```
ÿZ └
```

I am running it on windows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* array;
int current = 0;
int size = 10;

void add(char element)
{
    if (current == size) {
        size += 10;
        realloc(array, size * (sizeof(char)));
    }
    *(array + current) = element;
    current++;
}

int main()
{
    array = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    char c;
loop:
    c = getchar();
    if (c != '\n') {
        add(c);
        goto loop;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= current - 1; i++) {
            putchar(*(array + i));
        }
        printf("\nThe size of the string is %d", current);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not storing the retuned value of `realloc`

Comment: To begin with, [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) ***returns*** the (probably) new pointer.

Comment: And don't use `goto` for loop. Use a proper loop.

Comment: Today in 'Why you should read the documentation'. Or just think about it. `realloc`... _reallocates_, right? So how will you know where it has reallocated *to*, unless you take some information back from it somehow?

Comment: Sorry, but this code has to be rewritten from scratch. Do not use global variables. Do not branch non-conditionally upwards. getchar() returns int. The use of realloc is just plain wrong. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

You are not storing the return value of `realloc`.

```
char *temp;
temp=realloc(array,size*(sizeof(char)));

if( temp )
  array = temp;
else
  // error
```

`goto` makes code harder to debug by generating a complex control flow.

If you think, you will see you can replace `goto` with a `for` or `while` loop too.

You can see that your else part is not part of the `goto` part. Once `else` is executed it's never going to execute again.

So create a loop with this(`else` part) outside the loop.

Also return type of `getchar()` is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this:

```
array=realloc(array,size*(sizeof(char)));
```

The memory may be moved to another location. That's why you need to reassign the pointer.

Of course, it is good to do some error checking too:

```
char *tmp;
tmp = realloc(array,size*(sizeof(char)));
if(tmp) 
    array=tmp;
else
    perror("realloc failed");
```